# Why the trees in water's reflection are looking smaller?

Tags: optics, reflection

Why do the trees in the image which are above the oval shape are below the oval shape in the water, Is that something to do with the perspective?

[image]

PC: Martin Damboldt ( Pexels )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax). The trees are not smaller — they are simply displaced to be higher (see how the ground level of the trees is above the middle of the circle). You're looking from above water, so you can see some things over the upper part of the oval, which are the tips of the trees. Same for the lower part of the oval, where you still see the tips of the trees *above* it (in absolute space, not the mirror-reflected one).

If you look from the water level, the picture should become more symmetric.